# update fields of conditionally rendered form

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, myfaces

my problem is, that I want to render form2 conditionally. This collides with a ajax update event of another form1, which should trigger the rendering of form2.

```
<h:form id="form1">
    <h:selectOneMenu id="selectedGroupId" label="#{msgs.group_group}" value="#{groupBean.selectedGroupId}">
        <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{groupBean.selectGroupEvent}" update=":form1"/>
        <f:selectItems value="#{groupBean.availableGruppen}" />
    </h:selectOneMenu>
</h:form>

<h:form id="form2" rendered="#{not empty groupBean.groupDto}">
  <p:panelGrid id="groupEditGrid">  
    ...
  </p:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

Is there a way of doing this without putting the render condition inside a component of form2?

Thanks
Jonny

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot update a component that is not on your page. But you could wrap your form in a `h:panelGroup` that is *not* rendered contitionally and update the wrapper instead.

Example:

```
<h:form id="form1">
    <h:selectOneMenu id="selectedGroupId" label="#{msgs.group_group}" 
                     value="# {groupBean.selectedGroupId}">
        <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{groupBean.selectGroupEvent}"
                update=":formWrapper"/>
        <f:selectItems value="#{groupBean.availableGruppen}" />
    </h:selectOneMenu>
</h:form>

<h:panelGroup id="formWrapper>
  <h:form id="form2" rendered="#{not empty groupBean.groupDto}">
    <p:panelGrid id="groupEditGrid">  
      ...
    </p:panelGrid>
  </h:form>
</h:panelGroup>
```